# Google Custom Search won't preview

Tags: css

I am a relative novice building a site using Dreamweaver. Am incorporating Google Custom Search but cannot preview in either "live view" or in any browser. It works fine when I upload the page to the server though. Here is the code...

```js
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.ESPRESSO});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('015741423371300019115:mbkcgdyu4bo');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
  }, true);
</script>
```

any suggestions how i can preview it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because of the following reason:
In line 2 of your code, you'll notice that you are accessing some Javascript code in Google's servers. Now, many servers have filters to restrict what sort of programs can access data from them. For example, browsers could be delivered the data while other agents like a bot or a screen-scraping program would be denied access. Which programs are blocked depends on the server. It is not unnatural that while previewing in your local machine the Dreamweaver program, not being a browser, is being denied access by the Google server. Or it may simply be that in the preview mode you access only local data and are disconnected from the internet. So it cannot access the Javascript.

In the following part of the code is some more Javascript related to your specific implementation of the custom search on your site. But you'll notice it uses functions that are not defined. These are defined in the Google server Javascript of the first part. So even this part fails to execute and you don't see any custom search rendered.